# drawing program that repeats different shapes

Tags: loops, time

Trying to create a program that draws a rectangle then square and keep repeating while the shape changes each instance in one second.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: where is your code ?!